# MySQL conditional UPDATE with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

What I am trying to achieve is the following: update an existing table where each row has field "order-id" (incremented sequentially from 0). Now, if a row is deleted I want to ensure consistency of "order-id", i.e. starting from 0, incremented by 1.
Example: Rows with order-id 0,1,2,3 - then row with order-id "2" gets deleted. I am looking for the SQL-statement that makes sure the order is not "0,1,3", but "0,1,2" ordered by the existing order-id (hence the ORDER BY in the subequery)

Here's what I have so far - works, but doesn't take ORDER BY into account for some reason

```
UPDATE walklist_walks AS w, 
   (SELECT walk_id, order_id,@n := -1 
   FROM walklist_walks 
   WHERE walklist=8 
   ORDER BY order_id ASC) m
SET w.order_id = @n := @n + 1
WHERE w.walklist = 8 
AND w.walk_id=m.walk_id
```

Here's some sample data:

```
   ROW 1: "walk_id 1059, order_id 0, walklist 8", 
   ROW 2: "walk_id 821, order_id 399, walklist 8", 
   ROW 3: "walk_id 91, order_id 45, walklist 8"
```

After running the query this should look like

```
   ROW 1: "walk_id 1059, order_id 0, walklist 8", 
   ROW 2: "walk_id 91, order_id 1, walklist 8", 
   ROW 3: "walk_id 821, order_id 2, walklist 8"
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you convert it to a `update-join` construct like

```
UPDATE walklist_walks AS w JOIN 
   (SELECT walk_id, order_id,@n := -1 
   FROM walklist_walks 
   WHERE walklist=8 
   ORDER BY order_id ASC) m ON w.walk_id=m.walk_id
SET w.order_id = @n := @n + 1
WHERE w.walklist = 8;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't do what it needs to:
Here's some sample data:
ROW 1: "walk_id 1059,
order_id 0,
walklist 8", 
ROW 2: "walk_id 821,
order_id 399,
walklist 8",
ROW 2: "walk_id 91,
order_id 45,
walklist 8"
After running the query this should look like
ROW 1: "walk_id 1059,
order_id 0,
walklist 8", 
ROW 2: "walk_id 91,
order_id 1,
walklist 8",
ROW 2: "walk_id 821,
order_id 2,
walklist 8"